# How to combine multiple SASS functions

Tags: sass

Is it possible to combine multiple sass functions?

For example i'd like to use `saturate` and `darken`

is this possible?

eg

```
color: darken(red, 5%)
color: desaturate(red, 15%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course! Just use the following.

```
color: desaturate(darken(red, 5%), 15%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized I could just assign the result of the first color as the argument in the second:

```
$darkend: darken(red, 5%)
$desaturated: desaturate($darkend, 15%)
color: $desaturated
```